# Applying filters on Google Cloud API - Instance list

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform

I was trying to filter GCP instance based on IP Range or subnet.

API : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list

I am able to use below CLI commands and get the list of desired instances

*gcloud compute instances list --filter="networkInterfaces.networkIP>172.23.0.0 AND networkInterfaces.networkIP<172.23.0.170"
gcloud compute instances list --filter="networkInterfaces.subnetwork:default"*

But I am not able to use these filters in API explorer provide by GCP.

When I use *networkInterfaces.networkIP = "some IP"* as filter I am getting below error

*"Invalid value for field 'filter': 'networkInterfaces.networkIP = "172.23.0.10"'.*

Is there any way we can filter the instance based on IPs?

I am aware that we can filter out once we get the response, but I am looking to apply the filter at request level itself.

Thanks,
Rmp

Comment: Please, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48697838/how-to-filter-by-networkip-in-gcloud-python-instances) and [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73455339?pli=1): right now it is not possible to filter by `networkInterfaces.networkIP` as the API calls does not support filtering by an array of objects

Comment: Thank you.. Is there any other way to filter instances using IP or by subnet?

Comment: You can perform a filter on your side. But not in the API call directly.